# Comment forum to display under the comment you're replying too

Tags: comments

I am making a theme where I have built in my own custom threading and such using twitter bootstrap. I have it now so that, as per default, when you click reply you are shot down to the WordPress comment forum.

Is there a way to make the comment forum come to you? to display right under the comment you are replying too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enqueue the `'comment-reply'` script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress).

```
function wpse88530_enqueue_comment_reply() {
// Enqueue the comment-reply script on 
//single blog post pages with comments 
// open and threaded comments
if ( 
    // Returns the value for the specified option.
    // 'thread_comments' is a Boolean option where
    // comments are threaded if TRUE, and flat if 
    // FALSE
    get_option( 'thread_comments' ) 
) { 
    // enqueue the javascript that performs 
    //in-link comment reply fanciness
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
}
}
// Hook into comment_form_before
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'wpse88530_enqueue_comment_reply' );
```